# Do rolling releases inevitably cause higher fragmentation over time than point releases?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, storage, rolling-release, defragmentation

Let's compare *Debian Stable* as a candidate for `point releases` and *Arch Linux* as a candidate for `rolling releases`:

**Does a rolling release by default cause higher fragmentation on the drive than a point release?**

Comment: I have no experience of rolling release, but don't imagine that it would be a problem, if using an `ext` file-system or most other unix file-systems. As they don't fragment much (apparently btrfs does fragment more). And this is not the type of behaviour that causes high fragmentation. I have never de-fragmented any of my Unix file systems. I have used Unix on systems I control since 1997.

Comment: Whatever the difference is, if there is any, will be irrelevant. It'll likely be drowned by the writes from actual use of the computer (your data, browser cache, etc.). Even if not, the user experience difference between the two choices is many times more important than the importance of any fragmentation difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distributions releases cycles and how often their softwares are installed/uninstalled/updated have nothing to do with disk fragmentation.

Disk fragmentation is only a matter of filesystems. Linux being usually installed on an "ext" filesystem, every "fragmentation" is automatically managed by it.

Welcome to Linux.

However, for stability reasons and since you've just landed on Linux (considering your question), I would suggest you not installing a rolling release-based distribution since they all have some breaking updates once in a while.

Instead, do consider using Xubuntu 16.04.1 then stick to it (do not upgrade to 17.10 or anything other than Xubuntu LTS since those are beta-grade releases, same goes for 16.10 and 17.04): http://ftp.lysator.liu.se/ubuntu-dvd/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Debian 9 "Stretch" is a very good distribution once you -will- learn not to jump on every new softwares, while prefering stability instead. But you must know what you're doing, that's why starting with Xubuntu as a playground is needed first.